# JBoss 6 max pool size issue

Tags: jboss6.x

I've recently started using JBoss 6.1.0 and ran into an issue with setting min and max pool size in oracle-ds.xml file. I tried two approaches (for both max and min pool size):

1. as a hardcoded number like `<max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>`
2. as a configurable variable like `<max-pool-size>${jdbc.maxPoolSize}</max-pool-size>`

While the first approach worked fine the second one didn't. When max and min pool sizes were set as configurable variables, the DataSource object created had max-pool-size=0 and min-pool-size=0. All other settings (being set as configurable variables) in the same xml config file worked as expected.

Has anyone else experienced the same problem with these 2 settings?